# Good reference of color-modifying functions?

Tags: math, image-processing, graphics

I can't find a good reference about color-modifying functions (such as contrast, brightness, gamma, ...).

*(Is there a more exact term for what I mean?)*

Would appreciate a tutorial with example pictures and implementation algorithms.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Platform and language is not so important. I'm interested in pure mathematic algorithms, so please don't point me to graphic APIs ;)

Comment: What platform/language? That information might be helpful. +1 to offset the premature downvote  :/   especially without some comment as to how this question could be improved.

Comment: You probably just want a decent reference book on image processing.

Comment: Yes, image processing is a good term, I also tagged the question with it. But I was thinking, that term is too general. In fact, searching for this term, I found a lot of information about things such as affinity transformation and graphic effects, but very few information about the specific topic "graphic functions".

Comment: I would add a tag of color-science here, but for the limit of 5 tags. A reference I might suggest is Giorgianni & Madden, or perhaps one of Hunt's books.

http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Color-Management-Wiley-Technology/dp/047051244X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1265512453&sr=1-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat dry, but usually thorough is the Color FAQ: http://www.poynton.com/ColorFAQ.html

Answer (score 1):

Only part of what you are asking, but probably useful:
http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Equations.html

Comment: Color space conversion, though being very specific, is also an interesting topic.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Charles Poynton's book](http://www.poynton.com/DVAI/), [*Digital Video and HDTV: Algorithms and Interfaces*](http://www.poynton.com/DVAI/), *hugely* helpful in this area.  Don't be fooled by the word "video" in the title; it contains all sorts of wonderful information about still images as well.  The explanation of gamma is especially good.  If you can't find the book at your library, the Poynton's [Color FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/Poynton-color.html) and [Gamma FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/Poynton-color.html) are also somewhat helpful.   But the book is really great!